# Finding the other factors of the polynomial and $K$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

If $(2x-1)$ is a factor of the polynomial $$p(x)=2x^3-5x^2-kx+3,$$ find $k$ and the other two factors of $p(x)$.

Comment: Do you know of synthetic division?

Comment: Hint: Find $k$ from $p(\frac{1}{2})=0$, then divide by $2x-1$ and factor the quotient, which is a quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2\left(x- \frac 12\right)$ is a factor of $p(x)$, therefore we must have that $p\left(\frac 12 \right) = 0$. Now from this we get that:

$$\frac{2}{8} - \frac{5}{4} - \frac{k}{2} + 3 = 0 \implies k = 4$$

Now just divide by $(2x-1)$ to get a quadratic equation which you can solve easily. In fact by Rational Root Thorem we can see that $3$ and $-1$ are the other two zeroes of $p(x)$

Answer (score 1):

by using the long division 
$$\frac{2x^3-5x^2-kx+3}{2x-1}=x^2-2x-\frac{k+2}{2}+\frac{3-\frac{k+2}{2}}{2x-1}$$
the remainder or last term must be zero
or
$$3-\frac{k+2}{2}=0$$
hence $$k=4$$
the other factors 
$$x^2-2x-3=(x-3)(x+1)$$